# What is the recommended way to iterate a matrix over rows?

Tags: julia

Given a matrix `m = [10i+j for i=1:3, j=1:4]`, I can iterate over its rows by slicing the matrix:

```
for i=1:size(m,1)
    print(m[i,:])
end
```

Is this the only possibility? Is it the recommended way?

And what about comprehensions? Is slicing the only possibility to iterate over the rows of a matrix?

```
[ sum(m[i,:]) for i=1:size(m,1) ]
```

Comment: mapslices? `mapslices(sum, m, 2)` does the latter

Comment: @jverzani mapslices does the job, although in some cases it will require I define an anonymous function. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: For any new readers, make sure you check out the answer by Seanny123, as it contains a good solution for v1.1+ that was not originally available when this question was asked and answered.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The solution you listed yourself, as well as `mapslices`, both work fine. But if by "recommended" what you really mean is "high-performance", then the best answer is: don't iterate over rows.

The problem is that since arrays are stored in column-major order, for anything other than a small matrix you'll end up with a poor [cache hit ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) if you traverse the array in row-major order.

As pointed out in an [excellent blog post](http://julialang.org/blog/2013/09/fast-numeric), if you want to sum over rows, your best bet is to do something like this:

```
msum = zeros(eltype(m), size(m, 1))
for j = 1:size(m,2)
    for i = 1:size(m,1)
        msum[i] += m[i,j]
    end
end
```

We traverse both `m` and `msum` in their native storage order, so each time we load a cache line we use all the values, yielding a cache hit ratio of 1. You might naively think it's better to traverse it in row-major order and accumulate the result to a `tmp` variable, but on any modern machine the cache miss is much more expensive than the `msum[i]` lookup.

Many of Julia's internal algorithms that take a `dims` keyword, like `sum(m; dims=2)`, handle this for you.

Comment: I think this answers my question, I will wait another day to accept the answer. I like this answer very much because it's made me realise that since Julia is column-major, I better arrange my data vectors as columns rather than rows.

Comment: The blog post you've linked to no longer exists. See http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#access-arrays-in-memory-order-along-columns instead.

Comment: 404 seems due to trailing slash. This URL works: http://julialang.org/blog/2013/09/fast-numeric

Comment: That was correct. but what about a 3-dimensional array?

e.g: `A[i,j,k]` . What is the order? `k --> j --> i` or `i --> j --> k` ?

Comment: Dimensions are ordered fastest-to-slowest.

Answer (score 27):

As of Julia 1.1, there are iterator utilities for iterating over the columns or rows of a matrix. To iterate over rows:

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

for row in eachrow(af)
    println(row)
end
```

Will output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Is there any way to also get the row indices using this method? That is, not just each row itself, but also its index.

Comment: Skumin, you can use `for (i, row) in enumerate(eachrow(M))`. In fact, you can apply `enumerate` to any iterator

Comment: What are the performance implications of using `eachrow(df)`? Is it comparable to a naive loop?

Answer (score 4):

According to my experiences, explicit iterations are much faster than comprehensions.

And iterating over columns are also a good advice.

Besides, you can use the new macros @simd and @inbounds to further accelerate it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not use the `eachrow` iterator, or nested loops, as I needed to zip `eachindex` with something else, and iterate over that zip iterator.  Hence, I wrote:

```
ncols = size(m, 2)
for i in eachindex(m)
    rowi, coli = fldmod1(i, ncols)
    elem = m[rowi, coli]
end
```

Note that this will only work where `eachindex` returns linear indexing.  If `eachindex` returns an iterator of Cartesian coordinates, you may need to iterate over `1:prod(size(m))` instead.