# Julia: how to iterate row by row in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, julia

Say that I have 4x4 multidimensional array A:

```
A = collect(reshape(1:16, 4, 4))
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5   9  13
 2  6  10  14
 3  7  11  15
 4  8  12  16
```

and I want to iterate row by row (i.e. `[1, 5, 9, 13]` first, then `[2, 6, 10, 14]`, then ...).

How do I do it? For now I have come up with the following:

```
`for row in 1:size(A, 1)
    println(A[row, :])
    # do something
end`
```

but I was wondering if there was a more "pythonic" way of doing it: kind of `for line in A: for element in line: ...`.

I also know about CartesianRange, but I would like to have an array-like row to work with at each iteration.

Comment: This question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778374/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-iterate-a-matrix-over-rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way to iterate a matrix over rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778374/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-iterate-a-matrix-over-rows)

Comment: Your PS isn't a dumb question at all — I'd split it out and ask it independently of the iterate-by-rows question.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks, I am going to close this question

Answer (score 11):

for visibility: nowadays (julia > 1.1) use "eachrow"

```
for row in eachrow(A)
    println(row)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because arrays in Julia are stored column-major, it may be wiser / more performant to just transpose the matrix (`A'`) and then iterate through it if you want to do a lot of things row-by-row.

Comment: Ok, but once it is transposed how do i get the behavior I want? I looked in to the suggested duplicate and the only way is through slicing. I don't get the "line" as in Python

Comment: Once you made the column-major matrix, you might as well use views.

Comment: Here are two issues asking for a function `rows` to enable `for row in rows(A)` https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14491 and https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl/issues/11

Comment: Maybe A.' is better answer. Currently nor A' nor A.' support structural transpose and something like `permutedims(A, (2,1))` is necessary if A is for example array of strings. See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/20978 (there is chance that A.' will do structural transpose in Julia 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

A very nice package for this kind of thing is [JuliennedArrays](https://github.com/bramtayl/JuliennedArrays.jl).