Julia ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Nothing) when trying to define function Base.show
I am new to Julia and I am trying to learn the basics.
I started to build a Sudoku project. Here's a full list of what I have done:
I started by creating a new directory, and then using the pkg> prompt to generate a standardized directory structure for a project.
user@linux$ mkdir -p julia/sudoku
user@linux$ cd julia/sudoku
user@linux$ julia --project
julia> ]
(@v1.11) pkg> generate sudoku_project
(@v1.11) pkg> ^D
user@linux$ cd sudoku_project
user@linux$ julia --project

Just to say at this point I am not sure if this is the correct sequence of operations. I may be using pkg incorrectly here. At the point, all I am trying to do is initialize some standard project directory structure as a basis to start working from.
Next, I created a file containing some Sudoku library code.
This file: src/sudoku_container.jl
module sudoku_container

export SudokuContainer

mutable struct SudokuContainer
    data::Array{Union{Int8, Nothing}, 2}

    function SudokuContainer()
        new(
            fill(nothing, 9, 9),
        )
    end
end

function Base.show(io::IO, sudoku::SudokuContainer)
    println(io, "Sudoku")
    for row in sudoku.data
        for cell in row
            print(io, cell === nothing ? "." : string(cell), " ")
        end
        println(io)
    end
end

end

I then wanted to write a test for this, so I created a directory adjacent to src called test.
This file: test/test_sudoku_container.jl
using Test

include("../src/sudoku_container.jl")

using .sudoku_container

function test_sudoku_container()

    sc = SudokuContainer()

    @test size(sc.data) == (9, 9)

    @test all(x -> x === nothing, sc.data)

    sc.data[1, 1] = 5
    sc.data[2, 3] = 9
    sc.data[9, 9] = 1

    @test sc.data[1, 1] == 5
    @test sc.data[2, 3] == 9
    @test sc.data[9, 9] == 1

    io = IOBuffer()
    show(io, sc)
    output = String(take!(io))

    expected_output = 
"""
Sudoku Container:
5 . . . . . . . . 
. . 9 . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . 1 
"""

    @test strip(output) == strip(expected_output)
end

test_sudoku_container()

I also created a file runtests.jl:
include("test_sudoku_container.jl")

I tried to run these tests by starting julia from the directory julia/sudoku/sudoku_project, and then running the following commands:
user@linux$ julia --project
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.test()

This produced an error
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Test not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Test")` to install the Test package.

which I fixed
julia> ]
(sudoku_project) pkg> add Test
(sudoku_project) pkg> ^C
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.test()

However, I then encountered an error relating to iterators. I do not know how to fix this.
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Nothing)
The function `iterate` exists, but no method is defined for this combination of argument types.

Closest candidates are:
  iterate(::Core.MethodMatch, ::Int64)
   @ Base deprecated.jl:293
  iterate(::Core.MethodMatch)
   @ Base deprecated.jl:293
  iterate(::CompositeException, Any...)
   @ Base task.jl:55
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] show(io::IOBuffer, sudoku::SudokuContainer)
   @ Main.sudoku_container ~/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/src/sudoku_container.jl:22
 [2] test_sudoku_container()
   @ Main ~/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/test/test_sudoku_container.jl:25
 [3] top-level scope
   @ ~/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/test/test_sudoku_container.jl:45
 [4] include(fname::String)
   @ Main ./sysimg.jl:38
 [5] top-level scope
   @ ~/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/test/runtests.jl:2
 [6] include(fname::String)
   @ Main ./sysimg.jl:38
 [7] top-level scope
   @ none:6
in expression starting at /home/user/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/test/test_sudoku_container.jl:45
in expression starting at /home/user/julia/sudoku/sudoku_project/test/runtests.jl:2
ERROR: Package sudoku_new errored during testing

Is anyone able to help me understand what is causing this? It seems odd.

Iterating over a two dimensional array yields each of the cells, not rows of cells.  Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778374/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-iterate-a-matrix-over-rows

(Iterating over a two dimensional array yields each of the cells in column-major order, not row-major order, because in Julia, array cells are in column-major order in memory.)

One possible fix:
function Base.show(io::IO, sudoku::SudokuContainer)
    println(io, "Sudoku Container:")
    (rowCount, colCount) = size(sudoku.data)
    for rowIndex in 1:rowCount
        for colIndex in 1:colCount
            cell = sudoku.data[rowIndex, colIndex]
            print(io, cell === nothing ? "." : string(cell), " ")
        end
        println(io)
    end
end


This output is most like display(sc.data), not show(sc.data) or print(sc.data).  Maybe the method could be Base.display instead of Base.show.  Base.show is for writing to files in a form that can be read back in.

I don't understand the comment you have posted below your answer, could you possibly provide further details?

But yeah I've tried to change to using indexes and it does indeed work

sc = SudokuContainer() so sc.data is your 2 dimensional array.  display(sc.data) looks similar to your output, showing the type on one line, followed by a line for each row of data.  show(sc.data) or print(sc.data) produces one line output, where rows are separated by semicolons, and all the data is within square brackets.

What's the difference between display, show and print?
